# Hashlib md5 in python returning incorrect digests for some unicode characters?

Tags: python, unicode, hash, md5

I have been playing around with python's and Java's MD5 implementation and encountered this quirk that's been puzzling me.

The following python script illustrates the problem:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import hashlib

def md5hash(x):
  m = hashlib.md5()
  m.update(x)
  return m.hexdigest()

print md5hash('\xdb')
print md5hash('Û')
```

Output:

```
98fd00d788afe2a5fa5e4f8e1666638b
31ecfb09f120720a55d96a2034f5d00b
```

I expected the two digests to be equivalent, given that `Û` ought to be equivalent to `\xdb`. I built an equivalent implementation in Java to get some more insight:

```
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    MessageDigest m = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");

    m.update("\u00db".getBytes());
    System.out.println(bytesToHex(m.digest()));

    m.update("Û".getBytes());
    System.out.println(bytesToHex(m.digest()));
  }

  final protected static char[] hexArray = "0123456789abcdef".toCharArray();
  public static String bytesToHex(byte[] bytes) {
    char[] hexChars = new char[bytes.length * 2];
    for ( int j = 0; j < bytes.length; j++ ) {
      int v = bytes[j] & 0xFF;
      hexChars[j * 2] = hexArray[v >>> 4];
      hexChars[j * 2 + 1] = hexArray[v & 0x0F];
    }
    return new String(hexChars);
  }
}
```

Output:

```
31ecfb09f120720a55d96a2034f5d00b
31ecfb09f120720a55d96a2034f5d00b
```

The output of Java is consistent, as expected. This is leading me to believe that `md5hash('\xdb')` is outputting an incorrect result, but I am not sure what it is that I'm missing. Any thoughts?

Comment: *given that `Û` ought to be equivalent to `\xdb`.*  That's where this falls apart.

Comment: `>>> print '\xdb'` yields `�`: an easy hint about your encoding error.

Comment: @JulienPalard: that depends on your console or terminal configuration. If I set my terminal to use Latin-1, that `print` would perfectly correct.

Comment: @MartijnPieters You're right, can't even though of anyone using latin1 today, sorry, so easy to make the mistake :-P

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your assumptions are incorrect. You started your Python source code with:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

`Û` is **not** equivalent to `\xdb` in that case; it is instead two bytes:

```
>>> u'Û'.encode('utf8')
'\xc3\x9b'
```

Python is entirely consistent here:

```
>>> import hashlib
>>> hashlib.md5('\xc3\x9b').hexdigest()
'31ecfb09f120720a55d96a2034f5d00b'
>>> hashlib.md5('\xdb').hexdigest()
'98fd00d788afe2a5fa5e4f8e1666638b'
```

In Java you started with a Unicode codepoint instead, converting that to UTF-8 bytes:

```
"\u00db".getBytes()
```

The Python equivalent would be to use a `unicode` string literal and either a `\uhhhh` or `\xhh` escape sequence:

```
>>> u'\u00db'.encode('utf8')
'\xc3\x9b'
>>> u'\xdb'.encode('utf8')
'\xc3\x9b'
```

Note the `u` prefix to produce a `unicode` string. `\xdb` without a `u` prefix is a *byte string*, not a Unicode codepoint, and only if you were to decode it as *Latin 1* would you get the same Unicode string:

```
>>> '\xdb'.decode('latin1')
u'\xdb'
>>> '\xdb'.decode('latin1').encode('utf8')
'\xc3\x9b'
```

You probably want to study up on Python and Unicode; see:

- The [Python Unicode HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html)
- [Pragmatic Unicode](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html) by Ned Batchelder

and for completeness sake:

- [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) by Joel Spolsky

Answer (score 3):

> I expected the two digests to be equivalent, given that `Û` ought to be equivalent to `\xdb`.

Û is `C3 9B` in UTF-8, which you appear to be using (it’s the encoding you’ve declared). `DB` would be ISO-8859-1.

```
>>> import hashlib
>>> hashlib.md5(b'\xc3\x9b').hexdigest()
'31ecfb09f120720a55d96a2034f5d00b'
```

Ta-da!

Comment: `printf $'\xdb' | iconv -f latin1 -t utf8 | hexdump -C` converts your latin1 representation '\xdb' of Û in UTF8 (\xC3\x9B), this response is right, and '\xdb' was the latin1 representation.

Comment: @JulienPalard: Unimportant note: the `$` makes the `printf` redundant, so you could use `echo $'\xdb'` or `printf '\xdb'`.

Comment: You're right, I always use bash syntax for escaping so I can use them everywhere, but I also use printf to avoid "\n" for readability in my hexdumps, both works. (I don't use `echo -n`, not portable).